# How does Unarmed work with the dual attack perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So dual flurry effects unarmed but what of dual savagery?  If dual savegery does apply doesn't that dramatically increase damage output by 50%.

Also can't you increase the amount of the enchantment via potion to increase enchanting skill then create or is there a cap on unarmed fortification?

Last can anyone here verify that there is a so called "snap neck" animation critical for unarmed during sneaking I've heard talk but nothing more.

Comment: You might want to edit this into one question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A short Unarmed Primer for Skyrim:**

**Perks**

- Steel Fists - Steel fists adds the **base armor** value of the gauntlets to your attack.  Smithing, well fitted perks, etc do not affect unarmed damage.
- Armsman - Armsman **does not** affect unarmed damage.
- Dual Flurry - Dual flurry **does not** affect dual fisted unarmed attack speed (power attack or not).
- Dual Savagery - Dual Savagery **does not** affect dual fisted unarmed power attack.

**Equipment**

With the best set of enchanting + alchemy feedback loop, you are able to make an unarmed enchantment of +14 onto **Gloves** and **Rings**, for a total of +28 unarmed damage.

**Animations**

Unarmed attacks has a finishing animation just like all other weapons.  If the enemy is the last one alive and you perform a hit, there is a chance you will perform a neck snapping attack.  If you are doing a sneak attack and you kill the target in 1 hit, there is a possibility of doing the animation as well.

**Race**

Khajiits have an inherent +15 bonus to unarmed.  This bonus may not apply while wearing gauntlets (I will need do some more testing to make sure).

Comment: The khajiit bonus applies with or without gauntlets but see I've gotten mixed results with the dual section, there are other questions on here to be precise where others claim dual affects Only the power attack as well as dual savagery I don't mean to not trust you but is there any proof you can provide it doesn't affect unarmed. In other words have you done more than a "I looked at it and it seemed the same". Oh and thank you for settling the other parts to my question really bugging me ^^

Comment: @New Guy, I tested this extensively in game with my character, Punchy the Khajiit, and I'm 100% certain of it.  As for the speed affect, try the perks with two daggers and without, the increase in attack speed is VERY noticeable.

Comment: What about Juggernaut? I only ask because it seems like the base value would be increased. What about Heavy Armor skill? Such that fortification enchants and potions would increase damage as well? Is there anything in game that can effectively increase base armor values?

Comment: @Jason unfortunately, no.  Though you can probably mod a pair of gauntlets with high base armor.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for information on the topic of Dual Flurry:
I tested the speed with Dual Flurry 1/2 and 2/2
Dual Flurry 1/2 (20%): 43 punches in 30s - 1.433 punches per second
Dual Flurry 2/2 (35%): 42 punches in 30s - 1.4 punches per second
Obviously I miscounted somewhere, but I think its save to say that there
is no effect on unarmed by the Dual Flurry perk.