# How do you level up unarmed combat?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to level up unarmed combat (punching)?
I found a perk but I want to get better and level up!

Answer (score 11):

In Skyrim, there is no class skill to level up unarmed combat (or Hand-to-Hand). Simply punching things won't help you.

There are, however, ways to improve your unarmed combat.

> Kahjiit/Argonian: You Start off with a passive 20 damage if you are Argonian, and 25 damage if Kahjiit to unarmed attacks, these races make the unarmed warrior the most powerful threat early in the game.
>
> Heavy Armor: I take the full tree since you are going to be right up in the enemy's face at all times, but you only need 30 points to get the Fist of Steel perk that will make any gauntlet's armor rating your attack damage.
>
> Smithing: Armor is your weapon. Improve your armor for more damage.
>
> Enchantment: This is what will make you truly deadly. Once you get the power to enchant you will be able to add Unarmed bonuses to all your armor and become a wrecking machine.

Source: [giantbomb](http://www.giantbomb.com/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/3030-33394/forums/i-punch-giants-how-to-become-a-master-of-unarmed-c-524255/)

Comment: fyi fists of steel, without mods, will only add the [gauntlets base armor rating to your attack damage](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42840/3917).

Comment: [Unarmed Badass Viking Build by Robaz](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhBiNx749Zw). Hilarious video tutorial

Comment: You can only enchant gauntlets/bracers and rings with Fortify Unarmed.

Answer (score 2):

Go to riften and start the thieves guild stuff by working with the guy named brynyolf and doing his quests plant the ring and go to the ratway, in a room with an alchemy table and a lot of floor traps a guy runs up and starts punching you, no matter your race his gloves add 10 damage to your hand to hand.

Comment: Is this property disenchantable, or will you be better off with the perk?

Comment: The Gloves of the Pugilist(which Gian the Fist of the Ratway wears) are the only pieces of apparel in the game with the Fortify Unarmed enchant. if you want to make your own gauntlets and ring with that effect, you need to disenchant those gloves. You really want to put one of the enchants on heavy armor gauntlets so you can also take advantage of the Fists of Steel perk in Heavy Armor. Specifically, Daedric gauntlets as the have the highest base armor rating and will add the most extra damage.

Answer (score 1):

A good race to improve the unarmed is a Kajhit which has 15 points unarmed damage. Wear some items enchanted with the unarmed effect. There is a perk in heavy armor called **Fists of Steel** which makes unarmed damage 10% stronger.

Answer (score 0):

If you're an Argonian you start off with 10 Passive damage and Kajit 15 Passive damage. So The first thing I did is went to the Companions in Whiterun and leveled up heavy armor with Farakas.

Next I got the "Fists of Steel" perk and then you wear your strongest heavy armor gauntlets and the armor rating of the glove/gauntlets is your damage added to the Argonian or Kajit damage.

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively, look at applying one or more of the unarmed mods.

http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/searchresults/?src_order=2&src_sort=0&src_view=1&src_tab=1&src_name=unarmed&page=1&pUp=1

Comment: Maybe you could go into more detail? You have just linked a search results page of mods.

Comment: There are loads of available mods there, which all tweak the game in different ways.  

I'd advise that you browse through the most recommended ones to find a mod that will make the game more to your liking.

You can install the mods manually by copying the files to the ..steam\common files\skyrim\data folder or (a better option) download and install the Nexus Mod Manager and use the "Download (NMM)" option.

Comment: @DaveM Put up one of your favorites and describe what it does. Make the answer a bit more detailed and helpful. Here at SE we do not "just" link to a source, the answer should already stand on it's own with enough detail for the less gifted people. A good answer will earn you upvotes and points that you can use.